# How to read global system variable in Angular configuration file?

Tags: angular

I have created a global variable `API_URL` in OS.

The I try to read value of this variable in environment file:

```
{"API_URL" : "${API_URL}" }
```

But it returns plain text `"${API_URL}"` instead value.

Comment: Can you please add more detail to your question? I am not actually following, what do you mean you have created a global var in the OS? Where is that value coming from?

Comment: I have created system variable usign this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/51807/how-to-create-and-use-global-system-environment-variables/ The I need to read this variable in my Angular application in envirement file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser cannot read the systems environment variables. If this would be possible then I would be very afraid, since people would be able to access your machine, but luckily all the JS in the browser is sandboxed.

What I suggest you do is to store this information in some sort of JSON configuration file and then import that.

You can do this by modifying your `typings.d.ts`

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Then importing it into your component/module

```
import config from "./config/config.json";
```

You can then use it like this:

```
{"API_URL" : `${config.ApiUrl}` }
```

Example config.json:

```
{
    "ApiUrl":"http://localhost:3579/",
}
```

Comment: Anyway application works under OS, it directory in server(dist).

Comment: @OPV I'm not following? The browser cannot access the Environment Variables. The angular code is being run on the browser and not the server.

Comment: Okay, but how to do that in process build?

Comment: I am still not sure of what you are asking. If you are settings that variable in the build then you need your build system to modify the `config.json` from the example I posted.